# Designing Deep Q Network Loss Function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on my first Deep Q Learning network, and I'm having difficulties designing the loss function in Tensorflow. As the loss function uses both the current network weights and previous outdated weights at the same time (see second equation [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/dqn/DQNNaturePaper.pdf)). I see only two ways to accomplish this:

1. predict in advance all possible states of the outdated network when it is being updated and then use these values
2. use `tf.train.Saver()` and switch between the models for every back-propagation

Is there something more suitable for this in Tensorflow that Im missing out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the outdated weights in different tf.Variables to be able to use them later. I don't have access to any of your code, but I'd recommend running your model construction twice, and using one as simple storage. Another solution would be to modify your current graph with two of every variable and creating connections to the copies.

That is, if you're creating a TensorFlow variable A and you'd like to store its previous values as B you can do as follows:

```
A = tf.Variable(5)
B = tf.Variable(0)

# Use A to do something
A = A * 5
# Store the value of A in B
B = A

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(B) # Store A in B
    sess.run(A) # Run an update on A

print A, B
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to do so for an entire network?

Comment: You'd need to go into your model construction and duplicate every operation. In the case of a convolution `conv` create `conv_prev`. Each of these convolutions contains a set of tf.Variable. You would need to copy them on every iteration in the same way I did above to use this approach.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be very feasible then.. am i missing something?